# How to implement a real time bidirectional connection with server in android

Tags: java, android

I have experience developing in android and using REST services, but now I'd like to implement an online game for android. For example a tic-tac-toe for multiplayer, where a user can invite to other to play a game and each one receive the actions of the other in real time.

Using REST for this kind of apps would require constants surveys to the server for updates and its a bad idea.Isn't it?

My question is what are the typical aproaches for this kind of "permanent" connections. I just need some hints about the technologies and protocols in client and server for start searching and read :D

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sockets directly but for a game like tic-tac-toe, it shouldn't be THAT chatty, using REST would be ok.